# What is the meaning of sparse file in java 7?

Tags: java, java-7

In java 7 OpenOption "SPARSE" Hints that a newly created file will be sparse. What does that mean?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file

Answer (score 6):

A sparse file is one in which contiguous sections of the file that are all zeros may not be allocated disc blocks.  It is a way of saving disk space if you intend to create a file that will have large "holes" in it.  For more background, refer to this Wikipedia article - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file

As Joachim notes, many kinds of file system on many operating systems support sparse files, and have done for many years.  Java 7 is simply making this functionality available for Java applications to use ... where available.

Comment: It should be noted that this is *not* specific to Java, but is a general OS feature (just like files are, really).

Comment: +1 Memory mapped files are sparse by default on Linux and Windows (For Java 6+ and possibly earlier)